# ClearCase error while creating baseline

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I am using ClearCase UCM and I am getting below error while creating baseline or while performing any ClearCase activity.

The history is that I had 2 vobs created and then I had removed those vobs and recreated them.
I am not sure if the error is due to that. But How do I fix this error. I tried looking up to see which vob is referenced by this uuid but I am unable to find it.

```
ClearCase: Error: Unable to find replica in registry for VOB with object ID:"c8421ede.c19811e3.9827.6c:41:6a:1f:57:06"
ClearCase: Error: Unable to locate versioned object base with object id: "c8421ede.c19811e3.9827.6c:41:6a:1f:57:06".
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you removed and recreated those vobs.

If you have only deleted a vob tag and unregister, you can add a vob back with `mkvob`, or with `mktab -vob` + [`register -vob`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_register.htm).

[image: https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/images/rgy_ops.gif]

In your case, an "Unable to find replica in registry" should mean:

- either the Vob hasn't been properly registered again.
- or it references an Admin vob (with UCM, typically the PVob) which hasn't been added yet (as in [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21247263))

You can check the vobs tags and ooid in the [Vob registry](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/t_rgy_data_manage_addregion_mkvob.htm) (also detailed in [this article](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.books.cc_admin.doc/rgy-admin.htm)).

Comment: I added the vob back with cleartool mkvob -tag commmand. The vobs that were removed had ucm components too. I ended up removing those too and adding them back. We are using INTEROP environment. I checked the vob with the command cleartool lsvob and it seem to be pointing to the correct pvob

Comment: Okay. It looks like I found the vob that had that uuid. It looks like the unregister did not happen correctly and somewhere either the stream or activity is still referring to the old uuid. How do I fix this?

Comment: @user3533610 my point is: to add a vob back, you need mktag *and* register. Just adding the tag back won't be enough.